# Is there a better way to do if else statement in this context

Tags: java, if-statement

I have if-else statements like below:

```
if (b != 0. && a != 0.) {
    price = (b + a) / 2;
} else if (b == 0. && a! = 0.) {
    price = a;
} else if (a == 0 && b != 0.) {
    price = b;
} else if (b == 0 && a == 0. && LastPrice != 0.) {
    price = LastPrice;
} else {
    price = previous close;
}
```

The idea is that,

1. if `b` & `a` not equal 0 , price = (b + a) / 2;
2. if `b` is 0 but `a` isn't, then take `a`, vice versa
3. if `b` & `a` are both 0 but lastPrice is not, then take lastPrice
4. else we take previous close

However, the way I wrote it is very clumsy, is there a cleaner way to do it with better coding style?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can simplify your conditions, knowing that the `else` is only run if the preceding `if` conditions were false.

Comment: There's no reason to compare to `0.` (but no harm in doing so). You can just use `0`, and it will automatically be widened to double `0`. (But, at the very least, be consistent: sometimes you compare to `0.`, sometimes to `0`)

Answer (score 1):

This looks more like human reasoning and is thus clearer (while being no more costly for the computer):

```
if a and b are 0
  if last price is also 0 price = previous close
  else price = last price
else if b is zero /* and therefore at this point a isn't */ price = a
else if a is zero /* and therefore b isn't */ price = b
else /*a and b are nonzero, so */ price = (b+a)/2
```

Comment: Thank you! If we know that the case for price = (b+a)/2 is actually the most common one that will happen >95% of the time, is it true that we should put it first in the if statement?

Comment: On the one hand, no, because no matter how you arrange it it's O(1), and so we're really not going to notice any difference in speed. On the other hand, efficiency never hurts, so you can rearrange it that way if you prefer. I go for clean and clear over clumsy and efficient when it's barely noticeable, but it's a judgment call.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this using streams:

```
price = DoubleStream.of(a, b)
    .filter(x -> x != 0)
    .average()
    .orElse(LastPrice != 0 ? LastPrice : previousClose)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an improved if-else statement by removing some duplication checkings.

```
if (b != 0. && a != 0.) {
  price = (b + a) / 2;
} else if (b == 0.) { //don't need to check a not equal to zero, because if so we would have been in the previous condition.
   price = a;
} else if (a == 0) { // same here
   price = b;
} else if (LastPrice != 0.) { // same here don't need to check that a and b are not null already checked that case on the first line
    price = LastPrice;
} else {
   price = previous close;
}
```

or you could do some nesting of if statements

```
 if (b == 0. && a == 0. && LastPrice == 0.) {
    price = previous close;
  } else {
   if (b == 0.) { 
     price = a;
   } else if (a == 0) { 
     price = b;
   } else if { 
     price = LastPrice;
   }
}
```